# Apigee can't add TradeTracker Soap API

Tags: soap, proxy, apigee

I'm very new to Apigee.

I'm adding an existing WSDL service as a API proxy.
When fetching the SOAP functions, all looks good. Every single one is imported and are setup correctly.

When i then hit the save button the proxy is created, but are never submitting the revision to the server.

When looking into the problem I see that i get a 502 error back from a file named https://enterprise.apigee.com/gw/upload/[NAME]/tradetracker-api/?validate=true

Also a TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'b.then') are thrown from a file named 24efdbdd.proxy-editor.js

As i'm using Apigee's own website to add the proxy, so there's not much i can do about it.
This is happening in both Chrome 32, Safari 7 and Firefox 25 and the error has been there for at least a week.

I can't be the only one using Apigee's which keep's getting this error!?

Comment: Is this specific WSDL you are working with or is it happening with every WSDL? Is it possible for you download from Apigee and attach the proxy code (zip file)itself?

Comment: Is there an external reference in the WSDL file like ref=./some-path? The WSDL import tool needs absolute URLs for any references.

Comment: @Srikanth It's a specific wsdl : http://ws.tradetracker.com/soap/affiliate?wsdl
I can't attach the proxy code, since an revision is never made.
I pretty much just paste in the url and hit fetch and build.

Comment: @Michael Bissell Added link to the WSDL. All path's looks to be are absolute.

Comment: Just added a different WSDL, which worked fine. So the problem must exist in the TradeTracker WSDL.

Comment: Yeah -- tried your wsdl and discovered the same problem.  I'll kick it to the product team and see if they have any idea what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with the WSDL file format -- not entirely sure what it is as one WSDL validator I used said it was okay, and another one choked on it saying it wasn't able to parse the file.

I've opened an issue with the Apigee product team to see if A) we can identify the issue with this WSDL and B) improve the product to throw a proper error rather than timing out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand the problem with the TradeTracker API.
I've got a friend who works there, and i will ask him i he can come up with an answer. As you say, at least the system should throw a proper error, instead of just choking. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the next release that is scheduled for release on 2/5/2014.

Comment: Isn't this a comment?